# How to travel multiple navmeshes in Patrol.JS?

Tags: three.js, navigation, navmesh

I am using patrol.js. for navigation. On one navmesh I can navigate. Suppose I have to navMesh Can i navigate from one navMesh to other navmesh.
**code for one navmesh**

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.load( 'https://objpatroljs-zzcpndkpct.now.sh/navmesh.obj', function( object ) {


                object.traverse(function (node) {
                    if (node.type === 'Mesh') navmesh = node;
                });

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                geometry.fromBufferGeometry(navmesh.geometry);
                var zoneNodes = patrol.buildNodes(geometry);

                patrol.setZoneData('level', zoneNodes);

                Object.assign(navmesh.material, {
                    color: 0x009688,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    transparent: true
                });

                scene.add(navmesh);

            // Set the player's navigation mesh group
                playerNavMeshGroup = patrol.getGroup('level', player.position);

            });
```

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP4a9.jpg)

Thank You..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a path between two navmeshes, you would need to merge them into one mesh.